# Unzipping on Google Drive from PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have a PHP script that recurses through a directory structure, and uploads the files to google drive, however some of the directories contain 10000s of small files, which been google drive would take days to upload each directory. So I zip these directories and upload them as a zip file.

However once they are uploaded and stored on google drive, is there anyway, that I can unzip them from within a PHP script, obviously downloading the file unzipping, and uploading the individual files defeats the object of the zip.

Is there some other third part app or api that I can call from within PHP to get the files extracted?

Comment: Not sure these do what you want, untested, Internet search: 'google drive  unzip files to google drive'. Gave obvious links of: [github.com/googledrive/zipextractor](https://github.com/googledrive/zipextractor) and [app-zip-extractor-chrome-extracts-files-google-drive/](http://www.chromestory.com/2014/01/app-zip-extractor-chrome-extracts-files-google-drive/) which look interesting.

Comment: Thanks I'd found those, but not sure how they could be controlled from PHP

Comment: From my understanding the zipextractor script downloads, extracts and uploads files, so although the problem is moved off my local uplink, the issue with creating 10000s of small files on google drive, will probably still exist.